# Adobe Audition CS6 turning off playback while recording

Tags: audio-recording, hearing, adobe

I am trying to shut the sound when recording myself in adobe audition cs6.
I just cant find where in the setting I can turn it off.

Because I don't like listing to myself in echo when recording myself.

Anyone know how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mute the track you are recording to and make sure to turn off the microphone in windows playback.